# Show that a vector field is a symmetry for a Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, vector-fields

Let Lagrange function be
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x_1}^2+\dot{x_2}^2+\dot{x_3}^2)-U((x_1^2+x_2^2,x_3)).
$$
Show, that vector field $\vec{Y}(\vec{x})=(-x_2,x_1,0)$ comply
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{s}\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}Y_j+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_j}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{s}\frac{\partial Y_j}{\partial x_k}\dot{x_k}+\frac{\partial Y_j}{\partial t}\right)\right]=0
$$

It is obvious, that $\frac{\partial Y_j}{\partial t}=0$, so I can simplify it a bit into
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{s}\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}Y_j+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_j}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{s}\frac{\partial Y_j}{\partial x_k}\dot{x_k}\right)\right]=0
$$
Than $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_j}}=m\dot{x_j}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{s}\frac{\partial Y_j}{\partial x_k}\dot{x_k}=(-1)\dot{x_2}+\dot{x_1}$, thus 
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_j}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{s}\frac{\partial Y_j}{\partial x_k}\dot{x_k}\right)=-m\dot{x}_1\dot{x}_2+m\dot{x}_2\dot{x}_1=0
$$
And the rest
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{s}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j}Y_j\right)=2x_1(-x_2)+2x_2(x_1)=0
$$
Is that right?